# Migration to ASP.NET 3.1 - routing from Login Controller to Razor Page Home Index page no longer working

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, authorization, razor-pages

I have upgraded my application from 2.2 to ASP.NET core 3.1. However, the routing from my AuthenticationController Login action, following a successful login, to the RazorPage Home area Index page no longer works. Here is the relevant pieces of my code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app

    // Add JWToken to all incoming HTTP Request Header
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var JWToken = context.Session.GetString("JWToken");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JWToken))
        {
            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWToken);
        }
        await next();
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                                     name: "default",
                                     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}

// AuthenticationController
public class AuthenticationController : Controller { 
    ... 

    [HttpPost] 
    public async Task Login([Bind("Id, UserName, Password, EmailAddress")]UserLoginDetails login) {
        ... 
        // Successful user authentication - now time to route to Home Index Razor Page
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", token); 
        return RedirectToPage("/Index", new { area = "HomePages" });

        ... 
    } 
}

namespace PilotApp.Areas.HomePages.Pages 
{ 
    [Authorize] 
    public class IndexModel : PageModel 
    { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

The RedirectToPage function results in a HTTP 401 "This Page isn't Working" error. Note that this routing works if I remove the [Authorize] attribute. So, why is the JWT based authorization not working in ASP.NET 3.1 that worked in 2.2?

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `return RedirectToAction("Index", "HomePages");`

Comment: No joy I'm afraid. It is a call to a Razor Page, so RedirectToPage is probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 3.1 seems to need the following cookie setup to ensure that JWT authorization works correctly:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {       
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        ...
    }
```

This has fixed my ASP.NET 3.1 migration issue :-)